# Can’t read from StreamingAssets in Unity (iOS and Android build)

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have made a program that reads data from a .txt file but when I build nothing seems to work. Desktop build works fine but iOS and Android doesn’t seem to detect the file in order to read it. I have a StreamingAssets folder inside the Assets and the .txt is right there.
I have tried these suggested paths for both the Android and iOS:

```
string filePath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets" + "/source.txt";

string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/Raw" + "/source.txt";
```

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

On platforms like Android you cannot access the streaming Asset files directly. Android uses a compressed `.apk` file. You have to use [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) to load the file. A different solution would be to use a [third party asset from the unity asset store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/better-streaming-assets-103788).